# vb.net WindForms Reportviewer error: Cannot create a data reader for data set "Orders"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022, reportviewer

Hi Hope someone can help me with this, I tried lots of posts but can't get it to work.  I am using vs 2022, WinForms, visual basic.  My reportviewer won't work, this is the error:

[image]

This is my vb code:

```
Public Class RptFrmDelivery
  Private Sub RptFrmDelivery_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Orders.Fill(Me.DayOldDataSet.Orders)
    ReportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report1.rdlc"
    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Orders"))
    ReportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RptFrmDelivery.Report1.rdlc"
    ReportViewer2.RefreshReport()
  End Sub
End Class
```

This is my report data:

[image]

This is my dataset:

[image]

Comment: You cannot have `.ReportPath` (with a wrong path, BTW) and `.ReportEmbeddedResource` at the same time. The latter defines a resource object with `Build Action = Copy if newer`, the former should define either an absolute path or a path relative to the executable. Note that this overrides what is set in `.ReportEmbeddedResource` -- Prefer the Constructor of `ReportDataSource` that defines both the name (first parameter) and the data object (second parameter). It's understood that the ReportViewer has been correctly configured, i.e., its source of data has been specified

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved this as follow:

```
Me.DeliveryReportTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MYDATASET.DeliveryReport, ModGlobals.reportdate.ToString())
Dim x = Me.MYDATASET.MYTABLENAME.TableName
ReportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
ReportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer2.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("MYTABLENAME", CType(MYDATASET.MYTABLENAME, DataTable)))
ReportViewer2.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MYSOLUTIONNAME.Report1.rdlc"
ReportViewer2.RefreshReport()
```